# What is the purpose of paada pooja and paada saranam of the elders and what are its advantages?

Tags: puja

Some times or on some occasions we are giving/doing (respects) paada pooja or "worship of elders feet" for senior citizens and this is only in `Hinduism`. Why we do this and what are its advantages?

Of course in some other cases why we are bowing to seniors' feet to get the blessings and therefore its our respects. (I'm doing always and I want to know the reason). Since we are always giving the namaskar with our hands.

Is there any particular reason?

Comment: I think you meant pAda meaning foot and not pAtha meaning reading?.. so edited accordingly. feel free to edit again.

Comment: exactly you are correct...

Comment: This is not particular to Hinduism. Also don't create Hindusim tag. It is meaningless.

Comment: At most my knowledge Christians and Muslims doesn't doing this. Hindus only following this and might be north Indians as well.

Comment: forget about any religion for a second. imagine a person falls at your feet. what are your feelings towards him ?

Comment: Right, thats the question I asked might be you got it. There is a chance to hug also and we can give a humble request with hands.